# Why is saved file from Java servlet a BMP when it should be a JPG?

Tags: java, servlets, jpeg, bmp

I store JPG photos in a database table and use Java servlets to render them in my web pages.  When I save one of my photos from my web page to my desktop, the browser saves the photo as a BMP file when it should save it as a JPG file.  And, the BMP file is 35MB when it is only 3.4MB in the database.  Could anyone explain how this could be happening?

Here is how the servlet is serving up the file...

```
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            inputStream = resultSet.getBinaryStream(1);
            if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {
                String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream);
                if (mimeType == null) {
                    logger.debug("Content Type is image");
                    response.setContentType("image");
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Content Type is " + mimeType);
                    response.setContentType(mimeType);
                }
                line = inputStream.read(buffer);
                while (line != -1) {
                    servletOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, line);
                    line = inputStream.read(buffer);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: how do you save it ? and show us the code from Image Serving Servlet

Answer (score 3):

Probably the reason for your browser to choose BPM is the mime type of the file.

Comment: I verified that the mimeType value is image/jpeg using the debug statements in the code above.  Also, somehow one of the replies to this post is no longer visible.  I hope I didn't accidentally delete it.